# Path representation algorithm

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

[image: Algorithm explained]
I am searching for an algorithm that could be used to represent an arbitrary path using set of circles. The idea is best described using enclosed the picture.

I would also like to know if there is similar solution using the ovals (since it would require overall less objects/path segments to be used)

Note: circles/ovals are required mostly because i would like to use this method to simulate path following using mechanical parts (like cogs / gear wheels) since I consider it visually appealing (please forget my taste)

Comment: Is there a real reason to use circles? There's a whole theory of splines that has much more flexibility and will represent many curves more simply: bezier curves, B-splines, NURBS, and many more.

Comment: What would the algorithm take as input?